# Differential Equation General form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I always knew that $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\sin^2 x=\sin 2x$ but recently I wondered what other functions have this property? Is there a general form such that $f'(x)=f(2x)$ obviously $\sinh^2 x$ and $\cosh^2 x$ but what is the general form of such functions. I've never really seen a differential equation like this but I'm extremely curious

Comment: I made all my answer based on your equation, but after that I thought that the equation should be $$[(f(x))^2]'=f(2x)$$